# Moving shape on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I was wondering what the best method was for changing the position of a shape within the canvas.

Here's what I have:

```js
'use strict';

(function() {

  const canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('canvas')[0],
    c = canvas.getContext('2d');

  //
  c.beginPath();
  c.moveTo(0, 50);
  c.quadraticCurveTo(0, 0, 50, 0);
  c.quadraticCurveTo(100, 0, 100, 50);
  c.quadraticCurveTo(100, 100, 50, 100);
  c.quadraticCurveTo(0, 100, 0, 50);
  c.stroke();

})();
```

```html
<canvas class="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

So right now that shape is sitting at 0,0. If I wanted to move it in the X direction I could theoretically do something like this:

```
c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(x+0,50);
c.quadraticCurveTo(x+0,0,x+50,0);
c.quadraticCurveTo(x+100,0,x+100,50);
c.quadraticCurveTo(x+100,100,x+50,100);
c.quadraticCurveTo(x+0,100,x+0,50);
c.stroke();
```

What's the correct way of achieving this?

Comment: Just like you wrote there. But you'll probably want to [clear the canvas first.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect)

Comment: Does this mean if you ever plan on moving an object around you should specify additional x and y variables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you ask ***"I was wondering what the best method was for changing the position of a shape within the canvas."***

The answer is 
**By using the transformation matrix**

Using direct manipulation of the coordinates is very inefficient.

The 2D API provides a full set of methods for transforming (moving) anything that is rendered.

These methods are;

1. [ctx.setTransform(axisX_X, axisX_Y, axisY_X, axisY_Y, originX,
   originY)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/setTransform)
2. [ctx.transform(axisX_X, axisX_Y, axisY_X, axisY_Y, originX, originY)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/transform)
3. [ctx.scale(scaleX, scaleY)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale)
4. [ctx.rotate(radians)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/rotate)
5. [ctx.translate(originX, originY)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate)

(links to MDN for each)

These will move anything that you render to the canvas apart from ctx.putPixelData

thus to move your object by x and y you can use

```
  c.translate(x,y); // move the following coordinates by x, and y;
  c.beginPath();
  c.moveTo(0, 50);
  c.quadraticCurveTo(0, 0, 50, 0);
  c.quadraticCurveTo(100, 0, 100, 50);
  c.quadraticCurveTo(100, 100, 50, 100);
  c.quadraticCurveTo(0, 100, 0, 50);
  c.stroke();
```

Or directly set the transform with

```
  c.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, x, y);
  c.beginPath();
  c.moveTo(0, 50);
  c.quadraticCurveTo(0, 0, 50, 0);
  c.quadraticCurveTo(100, 0, 100, 50);
  c.quadraticCurveTo(100, 100, 50, 100);
  c.quadraticCurveTo(0, 100, 0, 50);
  c.stroke();
```

These can be tricky to understand if you are not familiar with matrix manipulation as methods 2,3,4,5 from the above list are multiplications of the existing matrix. While method 1 simply replaces the existing matrix and is not effected by previous transformations.

Here is a very simple function that will move an object and includes scale and rotation.

```
// rotation is in radians and rotates the x and y axis
// scaleX scales along the new xAxis 
// scaleY scales along the new yAxis
// x and y translate to the desired screen coordinates
function position(ctx, x, y, scaleX, scaleY, rotation){
    var scaleRatio = scaleY / scaleX;
    var rx = Math.cos(rotation) * scaleX;
    var ry = Math.sin(rotation) * scaleX;
    ctx.setTransform(rx, ry, -ry * scaleRatio, rx * scaleRatio, x, y);
}
```

to call

```
position(ctx,100,100,2,0.5, Math.PI/4)
```

moves anything drawn after that call 100,100 pixels, makes it twice as wide and half as high and rotates it 45 deg clockwise

to restore to the default do either

```
position(ctx, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0);
```

or quicker with

```
ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
```

**For a more detailed explanation**

of how to use setTransform and why it is prefered over the other methods see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35953535/3877726)

Comment: Wow, great answer - I will have to update my code with these new methods - thank you!

Comment: Note that this moves *everything* so if you want to move multiple objects in relation to each other, you're still going to have to update their positions. For context, the canvas transform is frequently thought of as the "camera" in 2D games.

Comment: @Mike Imagine a game your character on a rotating turret, on a aircraft taking off from a turning aircraft carrier,carried by ocean currents, seen from a camera attach to a spinning bomber. Now add 1000 sprites, smoke, bullets, fire, waves, and more One matrix per sprite It does not matter how complex or deep the links are, to move the character forward translate(1,0), to double in size scale(2,2). Transforms make it so easy and if your character shots, every bullet moves 20 pixels along X per frame no matter what. Transforms are simplest and fastest way to render everything that moves.

Answer (score 0):

You've got the right idea. Just make sure that you're clearing the canvas between draws to make sure you're not drawing over what's currently on the canvas. Then you can just have some `x` value that you update and you can draw it anywhere. You could extend this to using some `y` value to allow you to move it vertically as well.

```js
'use strict';

(function() {

  const canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('canvas')[0],
        c = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var x = 0;

  function render() {
    c.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height); // Clear the canvas
    c.beginPath();
    
    // Adjust path based on x position
    c.moveTo(x, 50);
    c.quadraticCurveTo(x, 0, x + 50, 0);
    c.quadraticCurveTo(x + 100, 0, x + 100, 50);
    c.quadraticCurveTo(x + 100, 100, x + 50, 100);
    c.quadraticCurveTo(x, 100, x, 50);
    c.stroke();
    
    // Doing this for animation
    x += 5;
    if (x > canvas.width) {
      x = -100;
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  render();
})();
```

```html
<canvas class="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```